# (vsftpd) uploaded file group

Tags: permissions, group, vsftpd

I'm creating an ftp server with vsftpd, and I've almost finished, the only thing remaining is when I upload a file (logged as an user U), the file belongs to a group which has the same name (so group name = U), but the user is in a different group.

Let's give an example:

---

user=publichttp

usergroup=ftpusers (and only 1 group)

When I upload a file, the file is uploaded with 775 permissions as I want, but a ls -l show me the file owner is publichttp:publichttp and not publichttp:ftpusers as it should be and as I want.

the folder permissions in /home/:

```
drwxrwxr-x 3 publichttp ftpusers 4096 nov. 8 17:20 publichttp
```

in /home/publichttp/:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 publichttp publichttp 98789 nov. 8 17:20 Extras.Txt
```

(I want)

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 publichttp ftpusers 98789 nov. 8 17:20 Extras.Txt
```

I don't know how to do that, searched all the day...

vsftpd.conf:

```
listen=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
ftpd_banner=myftp.

anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
nopriv_user=publichttp
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty

chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list #empty file
allow_writeable_chroot=YES

userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.user_list #just contains publichttp

anon_upload_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
file_open_mode=0777
```

Is it possible ? (the simplest solution is the best)

Thanks !

Comment: What `id publichttp` says?

Comment: uid=1005(publichttp) gid=1006(publichttp) groups=1006(publichttp),1003(ftpusers)

seems he still is in his homonymous group Oo -- (I changed his group with the user manager GUI, not in line, maybe it can explain ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vsftpd takes all information from /etc/passwd and /etc/groups with local users. To make your publichttp user uploaded files belong to ftpusers group, you need to set primary gid of publichttp user to ftpusers group in /etc/passwd.

Comment: Worked, thank you very much

(if anyone was searching for the same problem you can get all your gid in /etc/group)